# How to run process in the background without stopping the Gui in Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am making a gui and code is given below . when i click on copy button in the gui it gets freezed till the execution of process but i want to do other process at the same time.I did some research on Google and i got to know that if i run that process in the background then this problem gets solved. So please anyone tell me the easiest way to do it ?

**Code:**

```
import Tkinter as tk
import time
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x400')

def Number():
   for i in range(100):
   print(i)
   time.sleep(1)

def hello():
   print('Hello')

b = tk.Button(root,text='copy',command = Number)
b.pack()

b = tk.Button(root,text='display',command = hello)
b.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

**Expected output**

when I will click on copy button the function `Number` should run in the background and Gui should not be freezed and at the same time if i click on `display` button it should display Hello

Comment: use `threading` module and run it in on another thread

Comment: I saw that but i don't have any idea how to apply it @Stack

Comment: ok wait i will show..

Comment: Thanks  for response @Stack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to launch your number priting function in a thread.

This is a very, very rough example that knows nothing about when the launched function completes, allows you to start several counts simultaneously... you probably want to read on into threading if you want to do it properly.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import time
import threading

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x400')

def print_numbers(end): #  no capitals for functions in python
    for i in range(end):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(1)

def print_hello():
    print('Hello')

def background(func, args):
    th = threading.Thread(target=func, args=args)
    th.start()

b1 = tk.Button(root,text='copy',command = lambda : background(print_numbers, (50,))) #args must be a tuple even if it is only one
b1.pack()  #  I would advice grid instead for Tk

b2 = tk.Button(root,text='display',command = print_hello)
b2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: why lambda is used here  ? I am new in python so please tell me

Comment: if i want to pass parameter with it then how to do it ?

Comment: The lambda is there because background(func) would get evaluated in the instantiation of the ttk.Button otherwise.