# How to trigger again a callback function before the first call for that function has ended, if that function is an animation

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter, animation

Good morning,

What I am aiming for:

- I want to create a button that when clicked triggers a call back function (even if that function is still running). The call back function is a matplotlib animation

Module:

- For the GUI, I am using tkinter
- For the callback function, I am using a matplotlib animation

Attempt n1:

- I created a button with tkinter that triggers the animation

Problem for attempt n1:

- When I trigger the button, the function runs, but then I cannot push the button again before the function has finished its run. I want to be able to push the button while the function is still running and have the function stop and run again from start.

Code for attempt n1 is basically [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73984032/how-to-trigger-again-a-callback-function-before-the-first-call-for-that-function)

Attempt n2:

- I then tried to use multi-threading, so that the animation and the GUI run on different threads, but when I do this, I get "Starting a Matplotlib GUI outside of the main thread will likely fail.". This is the code for this second attempt:

Here it is:

```
import tkinter as tk # Import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk # Import ttk
import threading
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from random import randint



def button():
    thread = threading.Thread(target=func)
    thread.start()

def func():
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(xlim=(0, 1),  ylim=(0, 1))
    point, = ax.plot([], [],  '-')
    CumulativeX,   CumulativeY=[], []
    def animate(i):
        CumulativeX.append(randint(0, 10)/10),  CumulativeY.append(randint(0, 10)/10)  
        point.set_data(CumulativeX,CumulativeY)
        return point
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
    plt.show()


win = tk.Tk() # Create instance of the Tk class
aButton = ttk.Button(win, text="Click Me!", command=button)
aButton.grid(column=0, row=0) # Adding a Button
win.mainloop() #  Start GUI
```

Comment: You cannot call `plt.show()` directly if you already have a Tk main loop running. `plt.show()` attempts to create its own gui thread to display a plot, which ends up conflicting with Tk's own gui thread. You need to embed the matplotlib widget (i.e. the window that tipically pops up when you call `plt.show()`) into the Tk interface beforehand, then simply update its canvas upon pressing the button. [Here is an example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html).

Comment: Additionally, the only way for a worker (animation) thread to stop running prematurely is if 1) the main (gui) thread sends a "stop" signal over to it, and 2) **at some point during its execution**, the worker thread checks for the "stop" signal and the function returns prematurely. I don't have much experience with Tk multithreading applications, but you can probably use a [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) to "put" the stop signal from the main thread, and then "get" the stop signal from the worker thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining the example from jfaccioni's comment and your question code, we get something like the below (which works for me on Python 3.10.7)...

```python
import tkinter
from random import randint

import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.wm_title("Embedding in Tk")

fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
t = np.arange(0, 3, 0.01)
ax = fig.add_subplot()
(line,) = ax.plot(t, 2 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * t))
ax.set_xlabel("time [s]")
ax.set_ylabel("f(t)")

CumulativeX, CumulativeY = [], []

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
canvas.draw()

restart = [True]


def button():
    restart[0] = True


def update(frame, CumulativeX, CumulativeY, restart, *fargs):

    if restart[0] is True:
        CumulativeY.clear()
        CumulativeX.clear()
        restart[0] = False
    else:
        CumulativeX.append(randint(0, 10) / 10)
        CumulativeY.append(randint(0, 10) / 10)

    line.set_data(CumulativeX, CumulativeY)


_ = animation.FuncAnimation(
    fig, update, interval=1000, fargs=(CumulativeX, CumulativeY, restart)
)

# pack_toolbar=False will make it easier to use a layout manager later on.
toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, root, pack_toolbar=False)
toolbar.update()

button_quit = tkinter.Button(master=root, text="Quit", command=root.destroy)
button_restart = tkinter.Button(master=root, text="Click Me!", command=button)

# Packing order is important. Widgets are processed sequentially and if there
# is no space left, because the window is too small, they are not displayed.
# The canvas is rather flexible in its size, so we pack it last which makes
# sure the UI controls are displayed as long as possible.
button_quit.pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM)
button_restart.pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM)
toolbar.pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM, fill=tkinter.X)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=True)

tkinter.mainloop()
```

Though it's quite verbose, it's not very complicated:

- we are updating the image once per second
- the `button()` function sets `restart[0]` equal to `True`
- the `update()` function with either add another random line segment (if `restart[0]` is `False`) or clear the figure and start again (if `restart[0]` is `True`)